# Error: It shows 'class std::unordered_map<int, char>' has no member named 'contains'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, c++20, c++23

I have been learning about map's function lately. When I was trying to use contains, it keeps showing error. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, int> count = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}};
 
    for (int i=1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        if (count.contains(i))
            cout << i << ": Found\n";
        else
            cout << i << ": Not found\n";
    }
}
```

I had been looking for solution and I update the version of g++ and change the .json but it doesn't work.
The version of g++ is 13.1.0
c_cpp_properties.json: "cppStandard": "c++23",

I don't understand why it is giving a error. Is there anything that I missed? This is my first question here. Please don't be angry if you think this question is so silly

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with vscode configuration.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` has nothing to do with running your compiler, it is for intellisense only. You need to pass an actual option to the actual compiler, probably by poking some other `.json`. Configuring VSCode can be tricky. If you'd rather learn C++, my recommendation is to use some other IDE, or no IDE.

Comment: You need to add the C++20 compiler option to tasks.json. As already stated c_cpp_properties.json has nothing to do with compilation.

Comment: Now why VSCode requires you to specify something as basic as the C++ version in two separate places is something only the VSCode developers can answer. But you at least should be reading the VSCode documentation where this requirement is explained.

Comment: `tasks.json` is for the compiler.  `c_cpp_properties.json` is for intellisense.